# Rejoin developement history of a fork with it's original

Tags: git, merge, fork, git-svn

- I have two projects. One **original** and one **fork**.
- The **fork**'s initial state is an older state of the **original**.
- Changes have been done to the **fork** that have not been done to the original.


  - (All source is in *src/*)
  - (Some of these changes are heavy *lets-(move/delete)-lots-of-files* sorts of changes)
  - (These changes have been done to *data* not source)
  - (These heavy changes might be discarded. I can recover the entire data, but I would like not having to do this)

The changes to the **original** have been applyed to the **fork** *manually* at some points in the **fork**'s history.

Now I want to join both developement histories together in a way that the **fork**'s repo gets a clean history with both:
The changes from the **original** and from the **fork** in correct, chronological order.

### Graphically:

*(Remember: The connection between those histories are manual svn merges)*

```
         (I)--J--(K)--L--(M)--N---O fork
         /       /       /
    A---B---C---D---E---F---H original
```

*Should be turned to:*

```
    A---B---C---J---D---E---L---F---H--N---O fork
    |   |   |
    A---B---C---D---E---F---H original
```

#### Background:

*Both projects have been developed using SVN, both projectes have been converted to GIT and uploaded to Github.

The fork is based on a checkout only. Each sync with the* original *has been done using 2 checkouts, diff/patch and a text editor ;)*

Answer (score 1):

I manually added all the commits of the fork and the original with cherry-pick. Also I reset the state at the end and after each cherry pick with the original to the state after the manual merges in the svn and commited that state.
This is not really a god solution (the moved files are a huge problem, the solution for automated merges is dirty), but it is enough for watching and searching the history

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you basically want the original repo as is, but with the deleted/moved files matching the fork (since all changes made to original is already in the fork). Since the fork is actually not really a fork (based on a checkout) I'd probably try to replay the delete/move operations made in the fork onto origin.

With git log you can use the --diff-filter argument to find out which files that have been deleted and/or moved. It should be possible to parse the output of this command and do "git rm" (and "git mv" respectively) on this output.

To see what files that have been deleted you can do something like:

```
git log --diff-filter=D --date-order --reverse --name-status | grep -E '^D[[:blank:]]+'
```

which in one of my repos yields:

```
D       dwgdirect/lib_340/vc10/dbg/td_gi.pdb
D       dwgdirect/lib_340/vc10/dbg/td_gs.pdb
D       dwgdirect/lib_340/vc10/dbg/td_spatialindex.pdb
D       kernel/custom/dwgdirect/namespace.h
D       std/res/hdracking/db/editablesettings.db
D       std/res/hdracking/db/settings.db
D       std/res/hdracking/om.res
```

Do the same as above but replace D with M in --diff-filter and in the grep regexp to get moved files, e.g.

```
git log --diff-filter=M --date-order --reverse --name-status | grep -E '^M[[:blank:]]+'
```

Pipe the output to awk to parse out the exact file names and get rid of the D's and M's (I couldn't get awk to work on my cygwin so you have try this out for yourself). Wrap all this in a script that does "git rm" and "git mv" on each line in each sweep.

Comment: No, you misunderstood me, therefore I improved my question :). I basically want to ditch the manual merges and embed the commits from the fork into the original's history.

Comment: Roger roger. How many are the J, L, N and O commits? Are they like a handful or 154? :)

Comment: ~700. I am currently trying to rabase the fork interactively (to drop all svn merge commits) and then remerge with the original.